# The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type decimal which is a non-nullable value type

Tags: c#, .net, exception, linq-to-sql

An exception occurs when the following `IQueryable` is enumerated:

```
from record in dataContext.SomeTable
select Convert.ToDecimal(record.nullableDecimalColumn);
```

The error is an `InvalidOperationException`:

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type decimal which is a non-nullable value type

The documentation for `Convert.ToDecimal` says that it converts `null` to `0`, so it looks like it should work correctly.

Comment: Documentation for `Convert.ToDecimal` never says it will convert `null` to `0` in `LINQ-SQL`  ,I think it is quite misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ to SQL wasn't translating the `ToDecimal` method equivalently; it wasn't tolerating `NULL`. I fixed this by using `GetValueOrDefault` instead of `Convert.ToDecimal`:

```
from record in dataContext.SomeTable
select record.nullableDecimalColumn.GetValueOrDefault();
```

This caused the correct SQL to be produced, so the exception no longer occurred.

Here is my understanding of why this happens. LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework provide face-value *semantic* translation rather than *literal* translation. In this example, `Convert.ToX` is translated directly to `CONVERT` or `CAST` in SQL. This is the SQL equivalent translation, but not literal because it does not include the fine details of *how* .NET `Convert.ToX` operates. Specifically, the .NET one converts `null`s to default values.

This is a symptom of the fact that the code didn't express what its author (who wasn't me) was really trying to do, which was convert `null`s to default values rather than convert between data types.

In my opinion, this is also a symptom of `IQueryable` being a leaky and unreliable abstraction. I personally think it would be better not to use it in the first place and instead use something that's designed better such as a normal/fluent API. I think `IQueryable` completely violates the interface segregation principle because it allows an unlimited range of queries to be used despite only a limited subset being supported.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer so what actually happens ? I mean `translated` `CONVERT` returns `NULL` for `NULL` , It do not converts `NULL` to any default values .IS It??

Comment: I think so. In SQL, you can use `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` for `NULL` handling. I think `CAST` and `CONVERT` are just for type conversions.

Comment: yup `CONVERT` returns `NULL` for `NULL` and that value breaks your code ?? Well you can check your `Linq-SQL` translation by hovering over the query .

Answer (score 9):

If you wrote Query like this

```
tot_vat_amt = _pd.Where(x => x.VAT == 4m).Sum(x =>x.amount)
```

**Replace with**

```
tot_vat_amt = _pd.Where(x => x.VAT == 4m).Sum(x =>(double?)x.amount)
```

Hope this will help you